# New line and tab notes in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

These signs of new line and tab appeared when I launch[image]ed eclipse today. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the button highlighted in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: great! thnx! it solved the problem. it's first time encountering this in 2 years of working with eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors -> Show whitespace characters